# Maintaining an MVC pattern, making database calls from model using PHPs Laravel 4

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to maintain an MVC pattern using the Laravel 4 framework, in my last project I made all the database queries from the controller, I have now learned that is a terrible practice and I'm trying to figure out how to do the same from the model. Here is what I would normally do.

Controller

```
public function serve($company)
{
    $review = Review::select('head', 'body', 'logo', 'name')->where('company', '=', $company)->firstOrFail();

    return View::make('layouts.singlereview', compact('review'));
}
```

Model

```
class Review extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'reviews';

protected $guarded = [
    'id', 'company', 'head', 'body'
    ];
}
```

When I move the `$review` variable and database query into the model then I get the error on the view with undefined variable. How do I pass the `$review` variable from the model to the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for catching that spacing mistake @RobertRozas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you will still need to do some stuff with your Models in your controller. Use Repository Pattern do to so, which is pretty similar of querying your models in your controller, but being less verbose:

```
public function serve($company)
{
    return View::make('layouts.singlereview')->withReview(with(new Review)->getCompanyData($company));
}
```

And put the whole logic in your repository:

```
class Review extends Eloquent {

     public function getCompanyData($company)
     {
         return static::select('head', 'body', 'logo', 'name')
                     ->where('company', '=', $company)
                     ->firstOrFail();
     }

}
```

Comment: Would using the repository pattern here as you've suggested have any other positive impact on my application other than being less verbose? Is this pretty much the same thing I was doing just written differently?

Comment: It's not just less verbose there are a few benefits, the controller is thinner, the controller now just have knowlege that it can get whatever it needs via a single method and the SOLID's Open Closed Principle is in place, because you don't have to change your controller if something changes in your Review model or in the way you do your queries.

Comment: after implementing your solution, I get the error "undefined variable: company" in the model

Comment: Sorry, just edited to pass on your the company variable.

Comment: Okay last question, now that my original variable isn't there anymore, how do I access the data from the view?

Comment: You were just passing `$review` to your view via `compact('review')` and you still are via `->withReview()`.

Comment: Ah I see what I was doing wrong, my variables weren't capitalized. When you use `withReview()` I didn't realize it was passing `$Review` instead of what I had before `$review` all fixed now though, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Also, while you are on the subject of creating good code, you might as well check out Eloquent relationships. They may require database restructuring for certain occurrences, but most of the time you should be good.

With the code you have provided, I can assume that review and company are in a one-to-one relationship, so once this is defined, you can simply retrieve a company object, then do,

```
$review = $company->review;
```